# Error in adding project admin and users to the bim360 project

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I am trying to add project admin and users to the bim project with the `POST    projects/:project_id/users/import` endpoint.

Finally, I am getting an error:

```
  "errors": [
                {
                    "code": 2000,
                    "message": "{\"project_limited\":[\"BIM 360 Docs\"]}"
                }
            ],
```

If I add project admin in the BIM portal and activate service Document Management, my API calls works.

Why does it happen?

Comment: Let see if I understand, when you create a new BIM 360 project (no services added yet) you get an error when trying to add both the Project Admin and the User? or only the User? Also it works once you activate the service of Document Management correct? I think the project is not visible to the endpoint unless there is at least 1 active service on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in limitations to the trial account